# How specify an inner class of a generic class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code which works fine:

```
class ingen
{
  static class X
  {
    static class inner {}
    static class A extends inner {}
    static class B extends inner {}
  }

  static class Y
  {
    static class inner {}
    static class A extends inner {}
    static class B extends inner {}
  }

  X makeX (X.inner ... inner)
  {
    return new X();
  }

  Y makeY (Y.inner ... inner)
  {
    return new Y();
  }
}
```

Now I would like to write a generic for the `make` methods. But I can not find a way how to specify the inner class of a generic class. I tried this but it does not compile:

```
  <T> T make (T.inner ... inner)
```

Is there a way to write this generic?

Comment: How have you declared the Generic class?

Comment: It is a generic method.

Comment: Hmm. I guess you can't do that. Because `X` and `Y` are not related.

Comment: @RohitJain It would be ok for X and Y to inherit the same base class. Would that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just overload `make`?

```
X make(X.inner... inner) {
    return new X();
}

Y make(Y.inner... inner) {
    return new Y();
}
```

I don't believe there is a way to do that with generics, since there is no relationship between `X` and `Y`, so they can't be unified by a singe type parameter in the first place (although even if they were related it still wouldn't be possible since `inner` is static).

---

If you choose to redesign your classes slightly you could try something like this:

```
class Base {
    class inner {
    }
}

class X extends Base {
    class A extends inner {
    }

    class B extends inner {
    }
}

class Y extends Base {
    class A extends inner {
    }

    class B extends inner {
    }
}

<T extends Base> Base make(T.inner... inner) {
    ...
}
```

Although I would take a moment to step back and consider if this is really what you want to do. It looks quite convoluted, maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: It would be ok for X and Y to inherit the same base class. Would that help?

Comment: Right, this is the sort of thing you could do with C++ templates (which would generate separate methods based on the type argument for `T`) but not Java generics (which generates a single method).  `X.inner` and `Y.inner` are distinct classes with no direct relationship, and thus you cannot model it as so.  Even if `X` and `Y` had the same base class (actually, they do: `Object`), this would not work unless you replaced `T.inner` with a common base class between `X.inner` and `Y.inner`.

Comment: @ceving You might be able to do something with generics if they both extended from a common base class *and* the nested class were non-static.

Comment: @arshajii Please show me how to. Mike´s comment seems to say something different.

Comment: BTW: there seems to be no need for the inner class to be non static.

Comment: @ceving The whole idea makes no sense if the classes are static. Static nested classes are equivalent to top-level classes. I highly doubt the generic approach is really what you want.

Comment: Think about entities and attributes. A specific entity can only be created by attributes which belong to the entity. But that is the same for all the entities.